# Are image maps <map> deprecated?

Tags: xhtml, html

Are image maps  deprecated in (x)HTML?

Comment: Side note, depreceating is something that happens to the value of a car. Deprecation (with a hard 'c', sounds like a 'k') applies to obsolete APIs. I think it may be the number 1 most mis-pronounced word by programmers. Anyway, carry on!

Answer (score 24):

It is in the [HTML 5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-map-element) draft spec.

It also appears in the XHTML [strict DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd):

```
<!ELEMENT MAP - - ((%block;) | AREA)+ -- client-side image map -->
```

In short - it is part of both specs and is not deprecated.

Some people do not like image maps because they perceive them as not very accessible or discoverable, and as such there are other markup/css/javascript techniques that work better.

---

The map element doesn't appear in the [`obsolete`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#obsolete) section of the HTML 5 spec either. In fact, several obsolete features have a recommendation to use image maps instead.

Comment: You there are other techniques that work better. Care to list any?

Comment: @rtgibbons When I was tasked with creating a map of the US that would give users info for each state I ended up using the method described here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssmaps/  It kept everything on one page, was accessible and degraded gracefully.

Comment: Image maps are also still [part of HTML 5.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-img-element-image-maps). It is not listed in [HTML 5.1's list of deprecated elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features). HTML 5.1 is still work in progress.

Comment: If you wrote http://www.milliondollarhomepage.com/ in HTML5 would you use something other than `map`?

Answer (score 3):

For the record, it is also still part of [XHTML1.1 Strict](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/doctype.html#s_doctype) [with one change](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/changes.html#a_changes)

> On the a and map elements, the name attribute has been removed in favor of the id attribute

In the now dead XHTML2 [any element could have been an Image Map](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/mod-csImgMap.html#s_csImgMapmodule), effectively making a separate element for it superfluous, which is the reason it was [no longer part of the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/elements.html#a_elements).

Answer (score 3):

Image maps are still part of [HTML 5.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-map-element), of [HTML 5.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-img-element-image-maps) and of [**HTML 5.2**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-img-element-image-maps). The `map` element was not listed in [HTML 5.1's list of deprecated elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features) and is not listed in [HTML 5.2's list of obsolete features](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/obsolete.html#obsolete).

(HTML 5.0 became an official W3C Recommendation in October 2014; HTML 5.1 became an official W3C Recmmendation on 1 November 2016.)