# Is the HTML map tag obsolete and deprecated?

Tags: html

Should we consider using HTML map/area tags obsolete and inappropriate in any case and should we use instead svg/canvas/whatever else?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3528746/462015

Answer (score 5):

No. Map has a different purpose than SVG and canvas.

Comment: SVG is WIDER, not  that just different. Nevertheless there are some areas where I can imagine it is possible to choose between map or SVG. Proof link  - http://www.workwithchoicecuts.com/demo/html-image-map-revisted/index.htm

Comment: Is there an SVG equivalent to that?

Comment: I have to downvote this. Honestly, it actually does not answer the question I've asked. I hope two links I've provided convince you that, well, this answer is at least not complete)