# Image inside a parallelogram

Tags: css, svg, css-transforms, css-shapes

I have multiple images that need to be in a parallelogram shape like this:

[image: parallelogram filled with image]

They should be enclosed in `div` elements, in a carousel and link to video pages. However, using regular images causes bounding box issues with the links due to the transparent areas.

Which CSS property is used to transform the images into parallelogram shapes like in the above example?

Comment: also check this out: http://generatedcontent.org/post/26407228072/split-feature

Comment: in short: answer: 'Insanely possible'

Comment: Voting to re-open after my edit.

Comment: Another approach to this could avoid using divs and CSS entirely, and instead use an [`area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) tag to define a different polygonal region for each sheared-rectangle image in the carousel.

Comment: @ToniLeigh check edit history. First version was questionable. As it stands, I agree.

Comment: @Vulcan, `area` is [discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3530770/510036).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a method in transform for skewing objects.  The only thing you will have to look out for is that everything in the div will skew also.  So you have to apply it twice.  Once to skew the div a certain number of degrees and then again to skew the picture inside back the opposite direction.

For example if you do this to the div:
`transform: skewX(10deg);`

You'll have to do this to the picture:
`transform: skewX(-10deg);`

Here's a link to read some more about [transform](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) - because there's more then meets the eye.

Comment: @YourConscious He/she explains that you have to "unskew" the image.  Otherwise, it'll look funky.  Other answer omits this important point.

Comment: This is actually the answer.

Comment: Happy to help.  Good luck.

Comment: @NicholasPadula you should probably accept this as the answer, instead of the other one. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve a **parallelogram with an image** and maintain the boundaries of the link shape with at least 2 different approaches :

### CSS transforms

With one div and a pseudo element. The image is added as a background of the pseudo element. The div is skewed and the pseudo element is unskewed:

```css
a{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  width:20%;
  padding-bottom:25%;
  transform-origin:0 100%;
  transform:skewX(-30deg) translatez(1px);
  overflow:hidden;
}
a:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:175%; height:100%;
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/kreZqnx.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  transform-origin:inherit;
  transform:skewX(30deg);
}
```

```html
<a href="#"></a>
```

*Note that you will need to add vendor prefixes to the transform and transform origin properties for browser support (more info on [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)).*

### Inline SVG

This appraoch uses a [polygon element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon) for the parallelogram shape and a [pattern element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/pattern) to fill the shape with the image:

```css
svg{display:block;width:30%;height:auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 10">
  <pattern id="image" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <image xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/kreZqnx.jpg" x="-1" y="-1" height="12" width="12" />
  </pattern>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <polygon points="0 10 4 0 10 0 6 10" fill="url(#image)" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I misunderstood the OP, I'll edit the answer with the fiddle. Yes the `skew` will completely skew the div, and that will distort the image as well. So just 'deskew' the image with the opposite skew:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 100px;
}
.skewed {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-50deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-50deg);
  transform: skewX(-50deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.skewed img {
  -webkit-transform: skewX(50deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(50deg);
  transform: skewX(50deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -87px;
  left: -90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="skewed">
    <img src="http://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/car.jpg" alt="car" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably needs vendor prefixes.

Comment: I added the snippet :)

Comment: … but not -o- or -moz-

Comment: jsfiddle put those automatically, I'll edit them out.

Comment: That skews the image completely, not just a mask. Not what the OP is looking for. -1